# How does Kant derive the categories of the understanding from the logical forms of judgment in the Critique of Pure Reason?

Tags: logic, kant, concept, critique-of-pure-reason

I didn't arrive at any cogent and clear conception of the exact relation between Kant's logical forms of judgment and his categories, and most importantly, how he derives the latter from the former.

> "*The same understanding - and through the same operations by which it produced, in concepts, the logical form of a judgement by means of analytuc unity - also introduces a transcendental content into its representations, by means of the synthetic unity of the manifold in intuition in general. These representations are therefore called pure concepts of the understanding applying* a priori *to objects*" (A79, B105)

He gave this example concerning the category of community and the disjunctive logical form, which I think is really not convincing and obscure:

> "*...we must note that in all disjunctive judgments the sphere (...) is represented as a whole divided into parts (...), and that, as one of them cannot be contained under the other, they are thought as **co-ordinated** with, not **subordinated** to, one another...*
>
> "*A similar connection is thought in a **whole of things**... (as, for instance, in a body the parts of which reciprocally attract and repel one another)*" (B112)

We can at best talk about a certain analogy. But how can we assert the identity of the cognitive acts involved in each case?

I think I need clarification of the notions of 'judgment', 'concept', 'analytic unity', 'synthetic unity' and 'function', and how they relate in what concerns logical forms of judgment and categories.

Answer (score 4):

The missing piece for you seems to be the fact that Kant builds on the idea of "architectonic" borrowed from Aristotle, as he mentions in the paragraph following the first OP quote:"*Borrowing a term of Aristotle, we shall call these concepts categories, our intention being originally the same as his, though widely diverging from it in its practical application*". Aristotle  already "derived" a list of categories in his formal logic by classifying judgments, and Kant took Aristotle's logic as gospel, "*to  the  present  day  this  logic  has  not  been  able  to advance  a  single  step,  and  is  thus  to  all  appearance  a  closed  and  completed body  of  doctrine*" ([Preface to the second edition of CPR](http://www.stephenhicks.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/kanti-critique-pure-reason-2nd-preface.pdf)). So his job was merely to adapt the Aristotelian classification to his transcendental perspective. Here is an [SEP commentary](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/categories/#KanCon) on how he managed it:

> "*Kant begins from Aristotelian logic in outlining four respects in which one can classify any judgment: according to its quantity, quality, relation, or modality. In each of these respects or ‘moments’ of judgment, there are three alternative classifications; thus, e.g., in respect of quantity, a judgment may be universal, particular, or singular; in respect of its relation, a judgment may be categorical, hypothetical, or disjunctive, and so on.*
>
> *These Aristotelian ways of classifying judgments are the clue to discerning the twelve correlated concepts of the understanding. So, e.g., from noting that all judgments are either universal (e.g., All swans are white), particular (e.g., Some swans are white) or singular (e.g., Cygmund is white), we can arrive at the three corresponding categories of quantity: unity, plurality, and totality. Via this route, Kant ultimately distinguishes twelve pure concepts of the understanding (A80/B106), divided into four classes of three...*"

As for the first OP quote, it rather refers to the overall scheme of the architectonic rather than the specific task of deriving categories from logic. Kant's conception of the architectonic is different from Aristotle's, where the categories are supposed to reflect the most general structures of reality (Kant borrowed the term from Baumgarten, where it had similar metaphysical meaning). In the spirit of the "Copernican revolution", it is not the categories that conform to the reality, but rather the reality is experienced in conformity with the categories. But this turning around leaves the formal category/judgment relations essentially intact, so *given the forms of judgment* Kant does not dwell much on deriving the categories from them. Here is an explanation of Kant's grand vision of the unifying architectonic in [Friedman's Parting of the Ways, Ch.9](https://books.google.com/books?id=RBZpXCDrgsIC&source=gbs_navlinks_s), which I find illuminating:

> "*In the original Kantian architectonic, what Kant calls pure general logic (traditional Aristotelian formal logic) constitutively frames the entire
>   system at the highest level. The traditional logical theory of concepts, judgments, and inferences supplies the formal systematic scaffolding on which Kant's comprehensive synthesis is constructed. The logical forms of concepts and judgments, when schematized by the faculty of sensibility, generate both the table of categories and the system of principles, which in turn underlie Kant's constitutive theory of human sensible experience of the phenomenal world, as made possible in pure mathematics and pure natural science.*
>
> *These same logical forms, considered independently of the faculty of sensibility, then generate the concept of the noumenon, which remains merely "problematic," however, from a theoretical point of view. Further, the basic logical forms of (syllogistic) inference, again considered independently of sensibility, generate the idea of the unconditioned in general and the idea of freedom in particular. And both of these ideas also remain "indeterminate" from a theoretical point of view, although they nonetheless possess positive guiding force in the regulative use of reason. This same faculty of reason, finally, when applied to the determination of the will, also generates the moral law as a product of pure practical reason... For Kant himself, therefore, the systematic unity of all forms of thought-theoretical, practical, aesthetic, and religious - is grounded on the idea that it is ultimately the very same reason at work in all cases.*"

Peirce, who spent perhaps the most time analyzing Kant's derivation of the categories (three hours a day for two years, he says), and modeled his architectonic on Kant's, ended up reproaching Kant for the same thing Kant reproached Aristotle for, lack of principle:

> "*Kant first formed a table of various logical divisions of judgement, and then deduced his categories directly from these... The correspondences between the functions of judgement and the categories are obvious and certain. So far the method is perfect. Its defect is that it affords no warrant for the correctness of the preliminary table, and does not display that direct reference to the unity of consistency which alone gives validity to the categories.*"

Indeed, the parallelism between the two tables in CPR is rather transparent. The "principle" Kant claims distinguishes him from Aristotle, who "*merely picked them up as they occurred to him*", and provides the warrant of completeness to the categories, is in using the table of forms to derive the table of categories. But the former is ostensibly derived from syllogistic predication, not unlike Aristotle's, concepts being essentially identified with predicates.  Peirce, after he learned of de Morgan's logic of relations and himself discovered detachable quantifiers, had to scrap his original list of categories, and start from scratch, see [Murphey's Development of Peirce's Philosophy](https://books.google.com/books?id=NaW1QNYFYCgC&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

Is Aristotle's/Kant's derivation of the categories convincing? Not today. Kant vastly overestimated the completeness of his time's logical doctrines, as 19-th century logicians soon demonstrated with propositional algebra, multi-place predicates and detachable quantification. The list which seemed "exhaustive" under logic, where all one could do is predicate to a subject with glued-in quantifier, does not seem that so much anymore. To us appeals to the syllogistic seem like a mere analogy, if that, but to Kant it looked like the a priori structure of reason made flesh.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't think I have advanced further. You said that "Aristotle already derived an exhaustive list of categories in his logic by classifying judgements" and used this throughout your answer. But as far as I know, Aristotle didn't derive his categories from his calssification of judgements. He mentionned no such thing in the _Categories_, and the central point that Kant made concerning Aristotle is that "_he had no guiding principle he merely picked them up as they occurred to him, and at first gathered up ten of them, which he called **categories**_" (A81, B107)

Comment: So it's still obscure as to how he derives them and it really does require elaboration. But maybe the answer lies in that "_The logical forms of concepts and judgments, when schematized by the faculty of sensibility, generate both the table of categories and the system of principles_". I haven't yet reached the part concerning the schematism, so I'll see about that.

Comment: @Ouazzani I added a piece on "principle" and Kant's criticism of Aristotle. It seems to me that obscurity you point out is not so much in Kant's derivation of the categories from the forms, but in deriving the forms from his theory of cognition in a principled way. But on this he is in not much better position than Aristotle, merely "picking up" types of predication from the syllogistic. The chief justification is that thinking is bringing sensations to unity under concepts, i.e. judging, and forms of judgement are catalogued in formal logic, i.e. in the syllogistic. But why syllogistic?

Comment: Yes I do agree that there is the initial problem of the establishment of the table of the forms of judgments. But my question is really not about this. What I do not understand is "_The correspondences between the functions of judgement and the categories_". How can it be "_obvious and certain_" for Peirce?!

Comment: If my understanding is correct, what Kant is supposed to prove in the Metaphysical Deduction is that the twelve categories he listed are _a priori_  concepts, and that these are the only _a priori_ concepts we have. Given that this is not "obvious", the argument, I think, is something like this:

Comment: i) the table presented at A70 is the complete list of the forms of judgment; ii) we combine and unite our sensible representations in a certain way to generate knowledge, and this latter mental act of giving unity is the same as that of making judgments; iii) therefore the forms of judgments are also forms of the representations we get from this union of combined sensible representations; iv) therefore the forms of judgments when applied to sensible representaions are _a priori_ concepts and they are the only _a priori_ concepts we have.

Comment: The difficulty you and Peirce are talking about is that of premise (i), the rest of the argument deals with the correspondence between forms of judgments and the categories. But it is clear that there are difficulties and obscurities in this part too. First, even if Kant is probably right in saying that "_imagination is a necessary ingredient of perception itself_", I think that there is no contemporary philiosopher of mind or cognitive scientist who would agree with him that the mental act involved in forming judgments is identical with that involved in forming perception of external objects.

Comment: Second, even if we grant Kant this, how can he conclude that these forms of judgments applied to sensible representations are _concepts_, and then _a priori_ concepts? If they are identical to forms of judgments, then they are the various ways in which given representations can be combined and united, this is the best I can understand from Kant. But what does it mean then to say that they are concepts, i.e. represenations in which is united other represenations? And how does it make them _a priori_, i.e. not originating in experience?

Comment: Maybe it can be said that I am wrong in my notions of concepts and judgments which are not Kant's. But I must say that it's kind of a mess. Concepts, for example, are supposed to have a rule-like character: "_a concept is always, with regard to its form, something that is general and that can serve as a rule_" (A106). But he also said: "_It is therefore a concept only because it comprehends other representations by means of which it can refer to objects_" (A69, B94). I also don't understand how a judgment can be, similaraily to a concept, "_a representation of a representaion of_ [an object]".

Comment: @Ouazzani "*By this function I mean the unity of the **act** of arranging different representations under one common representation... The only use which the understanding can make of these concepts is to form judgments by them.*" To Kant, concepts are not rules as codes, but rather the acts of unification themselves. This Wittgensteinian streak is well explained in [Pippin's Kant on empirical concepts](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0039368179900025)

Comment: "*...the understanding is the faculty of thinking, and thinking is knowledge by means of concepts, while concepts, as predicates of possible judgments, refer to some representation of an object yet undetermined.*" So thinking amounts to predicating concepts to objects, judgments are the results of these acts. If we accept this then the syllogistic must provide all predications, i.e. all concepts. And they are a priori because logic (and mathematics) is a priori, this is Kant's starting assumption.

Comment: Peirce struggled with Kant's view of perceptions even more than with categories, its perhaps most elaborate contemporary successor was developed by Sellars. We have to distinguish sensations (seeing red X) from perceptions (seeing X as red), and the latter, he argues, *is* a judgment, and a conceptual judgement at that:"*one has no concept pertaining to the observable properties of physical objects in Space and Time unless one has them all - and... a great deal more besides.*" See [Empiricism and the Philosophy of Mind](http://mcps.umn.edu/assets/pdf/1_11_Sellars.pdf).